# Rust app failes to compile because CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR environment variable is missing

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I recently added a dependency to my Rust app that contains a procedural macro. This procedural macro is called with `i18n_codegen::i18n!("locales");`. It will find all files in the `locales` directory relative to `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR`. As far as I understand `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` is the root of your crate, and gets set by Cargo.

This works fine locally but when I try to build it on my CI server it fails with this message:

```
root@9eb2477f8a48:~# cd ./project/
root@9eb2477f8a48:~/project# cargo build --tests
   Compiling i18n v0.1.0 (/root/project/i18n)
   Compiling diesel-factories v0.0.1
   Compiling rocket_contrib v0.4.0
error: Could not compile `i18n`.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name i18n i18n/src/lib.rs --color always --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=7a0984ff3e085e3a -C extra-filename=-7a0984ff3e085e3a --out-dir /root/project/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/root/project/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/root/project/target/debug/deps --extern i18n_codegen=/root/project/target/debug/deps/libi18n_codegen-85460420d23be67d.so` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: Could not compile `i18n`.
```

Running the rustc command gives

```
root@9eb2477f8a48:~/project# rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name i18n i18n/src/lib.rs --color always --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=7a0984ff3e085e3a -C extra-filename=-7a0984ff3e085e3a --out-dir /root/project/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/root/project/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/root/project/target/debug/deps --extern i18n_codegen=/root/project/target/debug/deps/libi18n_codegen-85460420d23be67d.so
error: proc macro panicked
 --> i18n/src/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | i18n_codegen::i18n!("locales");
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: message: Env var `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` was missing

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Seems like `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` is missing... How can that be? I thought that was always set by Cargo? I guess it might be missing when running `rustc` directly, but how can it also be missing when running `cargo build --tests`?

The code that finds the env var is here https://github.com/davidpdrsn/i18n_codegen/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L233.

The main app itself it a Cargo workspace with a few other crates inside it, not sure if that matters.

I'm using the same version of Rust nightly locally and on CI.

It is a work project that is closed source, so unfortunately I cannot easily share it.

Comment: well, you mix up two issues here, if you launch with `rustc` obviously cargo thing will be missing ! But look like rustc has been kill by OS, that look like a bug somewhere, not enough RAM ?

Comment: _"It is a work project that is closed source, so unfortunately I cannot easily share it."_ Hopefully you can build a separate project that reproduces the same problem. And considering that you are using a nightly toolchain, it is relevant that you specify which one.

Comment: @Stargateur That seems to be why. I did clean build locally and memory usage by rustc peaked at 6 GB  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The first and second error are unrelated:

1. Fails because the process was killed from "some where" (The comments seem to have solved that).
2. Fails because `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` is set by `cargo` so if you run `rustc` manually you have to set the variable yourself, generally try not to run `rustc` manually at all.

Comment: Suggestion on avoiding `rustc` and use `cargo` generally, is helpful insight, and this question/answer shows a concrete example why.